# Как указать пути к файлам css, картинкок и других ресурсов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, python-3.6

Когда ставлю background то пишет мол картинка не найдена. Если Переместить картинку на уровень выше папки cgi-bin, то всё работает, но если создать папку параллельно cgi-bin, то опять не находит. Вопрос вот в чём: где хранить контент - яваскрипты, стили, картинки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения] В реальности папка recources выше папки cgi-bin, если переместить её в cgi-bin, то всё равно не пашет...
Вот код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

path = "<script type='text\javascript'>window.href</script>"

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <style>
            body{background:url(resources/images/bg.png)}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>""")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ссылки относительно текущего документа**

При создании относительных ссылок надо понимать, какое значение для атрибута href следует указывать, поскольку оно зависит от исходного расположения файлов.

1. Файлы располагаются в одной папке

Необходимо сделать ссылку из исходного документа на ссылаемый. В таком случае код будет следующий.

```
<a href="Ссылаемый документ.формат">Ссылка</a>
```

2. Файлы размещаются в разных папках.

Когда исходный документ хранится в одной папке, а ссылаемый в корне директорий, то перед именем файла в адресе ссылки следует поставить две точки и слэш (/), как показано ниже.

```
<a href="../Ссылаемый документ.формат">Ссылка</a>
```

*Две точки в данном случае означают выйти из текущей папки на уровень выше.*

3. Файлы размещаются в разных папках.

Теперь ситуация меняется, исходный файл располагается в корне сайта, а файл, на который необходимо сделать ссылку - в папке. В этом случае путь к файлу будет следующий.

```
<a href="Папка/Ссылаемый документ.формат">Ссылка</a>
```

Заметьте, что никаких дополнительных точек и слэшей перед именем папки нет. Если файл находится внутри не одной, а двух папок, то путь к нему записывается так.

```
<a href="Папка 1/Папка 2/Ссылаемый документ.формат">Ссылка</a>
```

> Вам нужно указать правильно путь к файлу!
>   А хранить данный контент нужно в отдельных папках

Вам нужно в каталоге создать разные папки с именем img, js, css, и т.д.

Пример картинки

```
/директория вашего сайта или что у вас там/img/bg.jpg
```